# Joomla seblod intro text layout?

Tags: layout, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using joomla 3.4.1 and seblod 3.5.0

When i make a new article using seblod, the full article layout i like it supposed to be but the intro tekst is now how we want it to be.
[Full text](http://i60.tinypic.com/24maj34.jpg)

We want to get a little box with some information like location, hours per week and education on the right of the text like the image below

[image]

Its now not showing the niveau location and hours part but it look like this [Intro layout](http://i60.tinypic.com/ouzbis.jpg)

Here is how my admin page looks like:
[image]

I hope you guys can help me out.

Date and location arrows are not supposed to be there

Answer (score 1):

SEBLOD has some manuals on their site relating to design like this - you can find it here: http://www.seblod.com/resources/manuals/designer/drag-drop-templating

Firstly, why are you using the Intro view to display your information? This view is really only used if you want to make a menu item with the native Joomla article blog view, which lists all the articles in a category. Instead of doing this, you will get better performance and results if you use a custom SEBLOD List & Search type to list your information.

If you're trying to control the layout of your information on your full article page, you should be using the Content View.

To achieve the layout you drew above, you would put your Image field in "TOP A", your Location / Date in "TOP B" and your article text in "TOP C"

Comment: Thanks for your answer we got the full article in the good layout already, now we need to get our intro in the right layout. The full article is now like this: http://i60.tinypic.com/24maj34.png that how we want it but the intro text needs a small block next to the text, the intro is now like this http://i60.tinypic.com/ouzbis.png.